# Does this forum support hobby rockets

Tags: discussion, scope

I mean, there is a difference between a Saturn V, which is impressivly tall, and a small 18 inch hobby rocket.

Does this forum accept questions about hobby rockets or only *actual* space exploration.

Answer (score 4):

It's almost never been discussed, but hobby rockets are considered on topic, or at least were when the site was created.